# Making and reporting a logistic regression, stratified by sex and age

Tags: r, regression, logistic, biostatistics

This question was already asked at Stackoverflow - R Language Collective, but they said this might be a better place to post this question, so here I am.

I'm doing the statistics in R. I have this database with over 6,000 entries and 75 variables. I want to make a few models. The outcome variable is always mortality. The first idea for a model is "Only take male/female, then stratify by age categories, youngest being the reference for the odd ratios (ORs) of the following age categories." (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYO7e.jpg)).

To do this, I first made a new dataframe with only all the female entries, and then in the `glm`-function, I subsetted by the youngest age-category (i.e. 18-39). Code looks something like this:

```
df_model_1_all_female <- df %>% filter(Sex == "Female")

model_1_stratgender_age_categories <- glm(mortality ~  Var1 + Var2 + Var3, family="binomial", data= df_model_1_all_female, subset = Age_categories == "18-39")
```

If i subset like that I'd have to make around 7 models (one for every age-category), for only the female category which already seems odd?

Furthermore, if I use this code to become the ORs and confidence intervals:

```
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model_1_stratgender_age_categories_default), confint(model_1_stratgender_age_categories_default)))
```

I'm not sure how to report this. Especially since the youngest age category equals the reference for the further ones.

I suspect I shouldn't use the subset-function in the `glm` like that, but I don't know how I should resolve it.

Furthermore, I'm fairly new to logistic regression all together. I can interpret an R `summary`-output of a regression, but I'm not sure how to adapt the model to make it better. Do you recommend certain practical resources to look at?

Comment: Why stratify?  Why not add age_categories to the model?  

glm(mortality ~  Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + age_categories, family="binomial", data= df_model_1_all_female

Also, if you have actual age, then you shouldn't categorize it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV! First, I don't mean to question your approach but it's usually better to run one large model with all of your data instead of running separate models for, say, men and women, let alone "women in age category 1", "women in age category 2" etc. Maybe you have reasons for this, but I'd consider if it was possible to run a model with everyone in it and use gender and age as predictors.

(However, technically speaking, you can use the subset function within the glm function the way you have specified.)

Second, I may understand your issue with reporting wrong, but to me model building/fitting and reporting are two different things. When you have run your model, take the statistics you want to report from your output and put them in a table (in one way or another). For instance, regarding your example, take the ORs and CIs and report them along with the coefficients?

Edited to add: if I run a logistic regression with a predictor with several category levels, I usually extract the mean probabilities for each level and report them along with pairwise contrasts. Emmeans package is great for this.

Third, regarding

> Furthermore, I'm fairly new to logistic regression all together. I can interpret an R summary-output of a regression, but I'm not sure how to adapt the model to make it better.

-this very much depends on what do you mean by making it better? Roughly, if you are trying to do inference (i.e. say something about the underlying population on the basis of your results), the best course of action is to decide what model you want to test on theoretical basis, and then stick with that model and report parameters from that model.

Whereas if your goal is to maximize variance in mortality explained in this particular sample, you can for instance compare pseudo-R-squared values or likelihood ratios across models.

Comment: By all means, question my approach! We want to report stratified by age and gender due to its clinical relevance. The idea I stated was given by my supervisor (e.g., another one is "(fe)male together, in every category a log.reg., female as the reference")

The thing is though, if the youngest age category is the reference, will they for all the variables be one? I would assume so, but have no clue how R would give something like that.

With "better" I meant "better fitting", as in, low AIC, high area under the ROC curve, etc. (All new terms for me, so do tell me if I say weird things.)

Comment: Yeah, I personally would never stratify a sample by potentially important variables (except for perhaps explorative purposes). In your situation I'd have all data in the same model, enter predictors, and have gender and age as additional predictors (if you want to know whether your predictors have different kind of effects on your outcome e.g. for men and women, you should enter an interaction term between gender and that predictor).

Comment: 2) I don't typically use model fit statistics (AIC, BIC etc.) at all when I'm doing inference (i.e. trying to make some conclusions about a population based on my sample). I think a better way is to just have a theoretically based model, test that and report whatever you get. If you are trying to just predict the outcome in this particular sample, and do not care about saying anything about anyone outside this sample then you can use AICs etc. to choose the best possible model (e.g. the one that has highest predictive power and lowest AIC, BIC etc.)